Is there an "intuitive" reason why we use Einstein tensor instead of Ricci tensor in GR?
As a thought experiment, if we assume that $R_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}$,
or for an even simpler analysis, assume that $\Box h_{\mu\nu} = -2\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$ in the context of linearized gravity, would it result in a "push" due to diagonal components $T_{\mu\mu}$ similar to interaction between 2 positive charges?
What is the intuition behind the trace reversal in Einstein tensor?

Hint: The energy-momentum-stress tensor must be covariantly conserved.

Physical aspect:
Einstein's equation of the form
$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} R = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}$$
just happen to be (at least approximately) true in nature. The equations describe the kind of world we live in. This is what experiments have underpinned.
Conceptual aspects
We can still ask, which kind of theories could be right in principle. Using
$$R_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}$$
is actually something Einstein considered himself before he found the correct equations.
As @Ghoster rightly hinted, the energy-momentum tensor satisfies
$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$$
and for the Ricci tensor in general
$$\nabla_\mu R^{\mu\nu} \neq 0,$$
so the equation $R_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}$ would be inconsistent.
(In my opinion, it is confusing to call this a conservation law, cause there is no conserved quantity in the absence of a timelike Killing vector field)
Remark:
In the vacuum case, the Einstein field equations are
$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} R = 0 \tag{1},$$
and taking the trace of this yields $ R = 0$, therefore $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$R_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$

You forgot the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

@Prahar I went through and fixed the 1/2 errors.

@Prahar thx. Such a silly mistake ;)

“The equations describe the kind of world we live in. This is what experiments have underpinned.” - No, this is what the experiments have disproven. (1) Any planetary of star system experiments use the Schwarzschild metric, so not applicable. (2) Galaxy rotation curves disprove GR without inventing unpredictable, undetectable, and thus unscientific “dark matter”. (3) The FLRW cosmology is in such a deep crisis with its “dark energy” absurd among others that it is not yet anbandoned only because “it is too big to fail”. So the equations in question fail pretty much in any experiment.
